# Hovering over <a> and displaying images based on value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently displaying pictures when an  tag is hover over. I have been able to workout the main problem of displaying the picture. The problem is that it has a glitch when hovering occurs quickly. Is there away to avoid that? Also how can i set a default image to display when page is loaded? [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/7Wp9z/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="links">    
    <a href="example.htm" class="large magenta awesome" data-content="cheeseburger">Cheeseburger »</a>
    <a href="example.htm" class="large blue awesome" data-content="tacos">Tacos »</a>
    <a href="example.htm" class="large red awesome" data-content="salads">Salads »</a>
    <a href="example.htm" class="large orange awesome" data-content="bread-sticks">Bread Sticks »</a>
    <a href="example.htm" class="large yellow awesome" data-content="dessert">Dessert »</a>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$("div#links > a").hover(
    function(){
        var ID = $(this).data("content");
        $("div#images").children("img#" + ID).fadeIn("slow");
    },
    function() {
        var ID = $(this).data("content");
        $("div#images").children("img#" + ID).hide();
    }
);​
```

Glitch

[image]

Comment: @j08691: Not sure it is a duplicate, the last question was dealing with how to display the images in the first place. The answer of the last question is how OP has implemented it, using `hover` and `data-attributes`. This question however, deals with issues in the recommended implementation. The current `hover` implementation has an issue whereby images are not hidden as expected. They are 2 different questions, addressing 2 different issues.

Comment: @FrancoisWahl well said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is that it has a glitch when hovering occurs quickly. Is
>   there away to avoid that?

This is not a glitch. `fadeIn` is using animation. As you are hovering over the links faster than the animations complete your experiencing that "glitch".

To ensure you are not clashing with the previous running animation you have to stop any current and any queued animation.

Replace

```
$("div#images").children("img#" + ID).fadeIn("slow");
```

with

```
$("div#images").children("img#" + ID).stop(true, true).fadeIn("slow");
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/7Wp9z/5/) - Clearing the animation queue before starting the next one

> how can i set a default image to display when page is loaded?

I added the code to show a default image as well. To prevent any odd visuals when hovering over a menu item the first time when using a default image. The code checks if we are showing a default image and if we are it will further check if the image for the current menu is the default image.

If it is, it won't hide it as it is showing it anyway but if it is not, it will ide the default image before fading in the new one.

Hope this makes sense, see the full code and DEMO below.

```
// Indicates if default image is shown
var showingDefaultImage = true;

var $images = $("div#images");
var $defaultImage = $images.children("img#tacos");

// Display a default image
$defaultImage.show();

$("div#links > a").hover(

function() {
    var ID = $(this).data("content");
    var $image = $images.children("img#" + ID);

    if (showingDefaultImage) {
        showingDefaultImage = false;
        if (!$image.is($defaultImage)) {
            $defaultImage.hide();
        }
    }

    $image.stop(true, true).fadeIn("slow");
}, function() {
    $images.children().hide();
});​
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/b7jQ6/) - Showing a default image

The code in the above DEMO is also a little more optimized by caching the selectors.

> would it be possible to leave up the most recent image from the last
>   hovered  tag ?(instead of hiding the image and leaving a blank)

If I understood you correctly you don't want to hide the image when you leave menu with your mouse but instead want to leave the image of the menu you last hovered over visible.

To do that you remove the second function of the `hover` and as it is no longer needed you can now attach the `mouseenter` event instead.

```
var $images = $("div#images");
var $currentImage = $images.children("img#tacos");

$currentImage .show();

$("div#links > a").mouseenter(function() {
    var ID = $(this).data("content");
    var $image = $images.children("img#" + ID);

    if (!$image.is($currentImage)) {
        $currentImage.hide();
    }

    $currentImage = $image;
    $image.stop(true, true).fadeIn("slow");
});
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/eHdZt/) - Fading in images on mouseenter and leaving last image visible

The above code includes caching of selectors for optimisation and the logic to ensure no "flickering" occurs when the new hovered menu item is the same as the last one which was hovered.

Comment: would it be possible to leave up the most recent image from the last hovered `<a>` tag ?(instead of hiding the image and leaving a blank)

Comment: @charliecodex23: I edited my answer to address the question from your comment. Let me know if that worked for you or if I miss-understood your comment.

Answer (score 1):

See http://jsfiddle.net/7Wp9z/7/

As François Wahl said, use `stop` to stop the animations. But instead of using `data-content` and IDs, I think that you could use index:

HTML:

```
<div id="links">    
    <a href="example.htm" class="large magenta awesome">Cheeseburger »</a>
    <a href="example.htm" class="large blue awesome">Tacos »</a>
    <a href="example.htm" class="large red awesome">Salads »</a>
    <a href="example.htm" class="large orange awesome">Bread Sticks »</a>
    <a href="example.htm" class="large yellow awesome">Dessert »</a>
</div>

<div id="images">
    <img src="http://media.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/images/brand-ux/cb.jpg">
    <img src="http://adventuresoflittlemiss.files.wordpress.com/2012/07/tacos.jpg">
    <img src="http://www.growingappetite.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/chicken-salad1.jpg">
    <img src="http://afflictor.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/breadsticks1.jpg">
    <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-IaURSrV70LI/T4YzPubl9EI/AAAAAAAAGSg/AEdd-eLuJUk/s1600/Cooking+Weekly.jpg">
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("div#links > a").hover(
    function(){
        $("#images>img")
            .hide()
            .stop(true,true)
            .eq($(this).index()).fadeIn("slow");
    },
    function() {
        $("#images>img").hide();
    }
);
```

Comment: This relies heavily on the order of the images to match the order of the links. That will make it more difficult to replace, add, remove images and anchors as the orders always have to match. This also increases the risk that the images are getting mixed up after an update.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl I think it isn't so difficult to mantain the right order, even when updating. But if it is for the asker, then your comment is a word of warning.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried not specifying which children should hide on the mouse-out portion?

```
$("div#links > a").hover(
    function(){
        var ID = $(this).data("content");
        $("div#images").children("img#" + ID).fadeIn("slow");
    },
    function() {
        $("div#images").children().hide();
    }
);​
```

Answer (score 0):

The glitch probably occurs because the image isn't loaded yet, you should look up some preloading technique. You will always have to wait for the relevant images to be loaded though before you can show them.

But you could enhance the user experience by either indicating that the images are getting loaded or by simply not activating the hovering effect until the images are loaded.

I'd probably go with the last case since I'm lazy but thats just me.

A simple preloading technique is to declare several id's with different background images and then changing the id dynamically using javascript and thus showing the image.

```
$("#id-of-element").attr('id','preloaded-bg-div');
```